# proplem in in using load with enterframe event in flash & actionscript3

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs6

hi iam new in action script3
when i use loader outside EnterFrame function  the code run corctly without this line

num= new Loader;
when i use this line the last show image under it
when i run code inside enterframehandler function no img apear[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKqhP.png)]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lkCF.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoD2B.png)

```
`var startGame:Boolean=true;`
var num:Loader= new Loader;
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler5);
function fl_EnterFrameHandler5(event:Event):void{
    if(startGame){
    
num.load(new URLRequest("flappy-bird-assets-master/sprites/0.png"));
box.addChild(num);
num.load(new URLRequest("flappy-bird-assets-master/sprites/1.png"));
box.addChild(num);
num.load(new URLRequest("flappy-bird-assets-master/sprites/2.png"));
box.addChild(num);
num.load(new URLRequest("flappy-bird-assets-master/sprites/3.png"));
box.addChild(num);
num.load(new URLRequest("flappy-bird-assets-master/sprites/4.png"));
box.addChild(num);
num= new Loader;
num.load(new URLRequest("flappy-bird-assets-master/sprites/1.png"));
box.addChild(num);num= new Loader;
}}
```

i try evry thig but cant solve this proplem

Comment: **First**: a single instance of **Loader** can load exactly 1 external image or **SWF** file. Instructing it to load multiple items will result in only the last one to succeed. **Second**: the **ENTER_FRAME** event executes each time a playhead would enter a new frame. Simply, if you have 25 **FPS** (default for **CS6** if I remember right) then you instruct your **num** to start loading over and over again. Without the **new Loader** at the bottom you don't get any visuals, with it you indeed create a new instance each frame, but it still ends up loading the last file only. 25 times a second.